# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions on real line.

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ be given by $$f_n(x)=\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{n}.$$
Then, it is easy to see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\cos x:=f(x).$$
Is the above  convergence uniform over $\mathbb{R}$. I tried to obtain an upper bound on $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ which is
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\bigg|\cos\frac{(n+1)x}{n}-\cos x\bigg|$$ $$=2\bigg|\sin \frac{(n+1)x+nx}{2n}\bigg|\ \bigg|\sin \frac{x}{2n}\bigg|.$$
How to proceed further? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence is not uniform. For example consider the sequence $x_n=n\pi$. Then,
\begin{align}
\bigl|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|&=\bigl|\cos(n+1)\pi-\cos n\pi\bigr|\\
&=\bigl|\cos n \pi\cos \pi-\cos n\pi\bigr|\\
&=2|\cos n \pi|=2
\end{align}
If the convergence was uniform, then for $\epsilon=1$ we would be able to find $N$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\bigl|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq 1$$
for every $n\geq N$. But this contradicts the fact that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|=2>1$ for all $n$.